# Bragg and Raman beam splitters

Tags: interferometry, braggs-law, optics

In atom interferometry, what is the difference between Bragg and Raman beam splitter operations?

When reading articles on atom interferometry I am finding statements such as `using a Raman/Bragg beam splitter' with little context regarding the difference. The only thing I can possibly think of is the types of regimes they are used in, if so what are these regimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Bragg beam changes the momentum state of the atoms without changing the internal state. For example, the momentum state $|p\rangle$ can change to the state $|p\pm n\hbar k\rangle$ where $k$ is the wave number of the standing light wave and $n$ an integer dependent on how many quanta of momentum have been imparted.

For a Raman beam the internal state of the atom also changes. For example, the state $|g,p\rangle$ can change to the state $|e,p\pm n\hbar k\rangle$, where $g$ and $e$ are ground and excited states respectively.